# How to force a XYChart refresh

Tags: java, javafx

I have two graphs that are plotted on the same stack pane.

They have common x and y axes and I want to make them scrollable.

Here is what I coded:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to draw layers of XYCharts.
 * https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2435995 "Using StackPane to layer more different type charts"
 */
public class LayeredXyChartsSample extends Application {

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> lineSeries1;
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> lineSeries2;

    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        initSeries();

        // Close the application when the window is closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        layerCharts(
                                createLineChart1(),
                                createLineChart2()
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initSeries() {
        lineSeries1 = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data(1, 2),
                        new XYChart.Data(2, 10),
                        new XYChart.Data(3, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(4, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(5, 7),
                        new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                        new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(9, 16.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(10, 13.9),
                        new XYChart.Data(11, 17),
                        new XYChart.Data(12, 10)
                )
        );

        lineSeries2 = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data(1, 1),
                        new XYChart.Data(2, 2),
                        new XYChart.Data(3, 1.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(4, 3),
                        new XYChart.Data(5, 2.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                        new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(9, 6.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(10, 13),
                        new XYChart.Data(11, 10),
                        new XYChart.Data(12, 20)
                )
        );

        createXaxis();
        createYaxis();
    }

    private void createYaxis() {
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
        yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(20);
    }

    private void createXaxis() {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setLowerBound(-10);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(22);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<Number, Number> createLineChart1() {
        final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries1);
        return chart;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<Number, Number> createLineChart2() {
        final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries2);
        return chart;
    }

    private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<Number, Number>... charts) {
        for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
            configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
        }

        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);

        stackpane.setOnScroll(event -> {
            double deltaX = event.getDeltaX();

            if (deltaX != 0) {
                xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxis.getUpperBound() + deltaX / 10);
                xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxis.getLowerBound() + deltaX / 10);
            }
        });

        return stackpane;
    }

    private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
        chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);

        chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());
    }
}
```

When I scroll with my trackpad on the side, only one of the two graphs is refreshed...

How come? I would like the second chart to be updated as well but I could not find a method in the XYChart class I can call to force a refresh. All methods that seem to do that are private...

**Edit:** instead of setting the onScroll listener on the stack pane, I also tried to set it on both charts. But it seems only the top layout gets the notification... So I have the same result: only one chart translating...

**Edit2:** I know that in this example I could just create one chart with two series and not stack them and that would work. But in real line, the stacked charts I use are of different types (a line chart and a custom chart), so I really need to stack them in a stack pane.

Comment: You can't use the same axes in both charts (nodes can't appear more than once in the scene graph). You need to create two sets of axes, use one set for each chart, and update both x-axes on scrolling.

Comment: Yes, that works! Do you want to post an answer and I will accept it or shall I write it myself?

Comment: Go ahead and write it yourself. (I'm on a phone and it's too hard to post an answer from it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @James_D (thanks a lot by the way), the solution is to use several x axes and to update each of them separately:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to draw layers of XYCharts.
 * https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2435995 "Using StackPane to layer more different type charts"
 */
public class LayeredXyChartsSample extends Application {

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> lineSeries1;
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> lineSeries2;

    private List<NumberAxis> xAxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        initSeries();

        // Close the application when the window is closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        layerCharts(
                                createLineChart1(),
                                createLineChart2()
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initSeries() {
        lineSeries1 = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data(1, 2),
                        new XYChart.Data(2, 10),
                        new XYChart.Data(3, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(4, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(5, 7),
                        new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                        new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(9, 16.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(10, 13.9),
                        new XYChart.Data(11, 17),
                        new XYChart.Data(12, 10)
                )
        );

        lineSeries2 = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data(1, 1),
                        new XYChart.Data(2, 2),
                        new XYChart.Data(3, 1.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(4, 3),
                        new XYChart.Data(5, 2.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(6, 5),
                        new XYChart.Data(7, 4),
                        new XYChart.Data(8, 8),
                        new XYChart.Data(9, 6.5),
                        new XYChart.Data(10, 13),
                        new XYChart.Data(11, 10),
                        new XYChart.Data(12, 20)
                )
        );

        createYaxis();
    }

    private void createYaxis() {
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
        yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(20);
    }

    private NumberAxis createXaxis() {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setLowerBound(-10);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(22);
        xAxes.add(xAxis);

        return xAxis;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<Number, Number> createLineChart1() {
        final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(createXaxis(), yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries1);
        return chart;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<Number, Number> createLineChart2() {
        final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(createXaxis(), yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries2);
        return chart;
    }

    private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<Number, Number>... charts) {
        for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
            configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
        }

        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);

        stackpane.setOnScroll(event -> {
            double deltaX = event.getDeltaX();
            if (deltaX != 0) {
                for (NumberAxis xAxis : xAxes) {
                    xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxis.getUpperBound() - deltaX / 10);
                    xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxis.getLowerBound() - deltaX / 10);
                }
            }
        });

        return stackpane;
    }

    private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<Number, Number> chart) {
        chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
        chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);

        chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());
    }
}
```